# Will GCC compiler or anything else update if I install Atom Editor?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, gcc, atom

I want to install [atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux) in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS like this:

```
# Install Atom
$sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb
# Install Atom's dependencies if they are missing
$sudo apt-get -f install
```

Will Atom work without dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-cache show atom-amd64.deb` to check your system to see if there are unmet dependencies which would be installed. Compare their versions to what you have now for each of those dependencies.

Comment: It didn't work, so do I need to install atom first? Will atom work without dependencies?

Comment: 1) Did you run it in the directory you downloaded atom-amd64.deb into? 2) Was was the error message? Please click [edit] and provide the error message.